# Javascript RegExp should check four-digit input for plausibility

Tags: javascript, html, regex, error-handling, hex

I want to program a JavaScript code which checks the input into an input field if it is a double two-digit HEX value. The input must contain exactly 4 digits and letters between a to f and/or 0 to 9. The following code leads to an error with a four digit input.

```js
function check() {
var input = (document.getElementById("textField").value);


if (input.length == 4 && input.match([A-Fa-f0-9])) { alert("the input matches the requirements");}
          else {alert("input is invalid");}
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textField">
<button type="button" onclick="check()">check!</button>
```

Comment: Regexes are defined with `/.../` - `input.match(/[A-Fa-f0-9]+/)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using regex you can define the length and simplify your test. You need to put your regex string in  `'/` `/'`.

```
if (input.match('/[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}/')) { ... }
```